# How does React autogenerate keys in nested lists?

Tags: reactjs

I have a case of highly nested keys within a React component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Lg } from "./lg.jsx";
import { L } from "./l.jsx";
import { Caesura } from "./caesura.jsx";

export const Poem = ({ poem }) => {
    return poem.map(stanza => <Lg>{
        stanza.map(line => <L>{
            line.map((segment, index) =>
                <React.Fragment key={segment}>{
                    index === 0 ?
                        segment :
                        <><Caesura />{segment}</>
                }</React.Fragment>)
        }</L>)
    }</Lg>);
};

export default Poem;
```

I am not at all sure how React will handle keys in this case. I might not be able to come up with a better solution.

I am rendering poetry in a highly regular format (for other cases I used custom mdx.)

> And did those feet in ancient time
> Walk upon Englands mountains green:
> And was the holy Lamb of God,
> On Englands pleasant pastures seen!
>
> And did the Countenance Divine,
> Shine forth upon our clouded hills?
> And was Jerusalem builded here,
> Among these dark Satanic Mills?

Ought to be result in a tree of components like

```
<Lg>
<L>And did those feet in ancient time</L>
<L>Walk upon Englands mountains green:</L>
<L>And was the holy Lamb of God,</L>
<L>On Englands pleasant pastures seen!</L>
</Lg>
<Lg>
<L>And did the Countenance Divine,</L>
<L>Shine forth upon our clouded hills?</L>
<L>And was Jerusalem builded here,</L>
<L>Among these dark Satanic Mills?</L>
</Lg>
```